# RESTful API Client best practices

Tags: java, api, rest, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

There are a lot of best practices about writing RESTful API Services, but it hard to find any useful information about writing scalable, easy to maintain and well structured RESTful API Services client.

**Short description on architecture that I use:**

I have a web application written using Java language and Spring MVC on the back-end and HTML+CSS+JavaScript+AJAX on the front-end.

I divided my back-end part of the Client into 3 parts:

1. Data access objects level (here requests to the API are encapsulated, so I can easily change implementation of it, e.g. move from URLConnection to Spring RestTemplate);
2. Aggregation level (here data from different API methods is aggregated);
3. Controller level (for communication with front-end).

**Questions:**

As for me, it is very flexible architecture. However, many of my friends says that DAO level can be used only for communication with databases.

1. Should I rename my DAO classes. E.g. from "CarDAO" to "CarRepository", etc?
2. Is it good architecture of RESTful API Client?
3. What can be improved? Can the same flexibility be reached with the less number of levels?

Comment: **Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.** *If the question has the term **best** in it, it is most likely way off topic*

Answer (score 2):

You can improve dao layer.

1) Create a dao service and dao objects seperately.
Service gets info from the dao layer where the dao implementation can be changed to another, along with replace dao layer with dummy data layer for test data. Use JPA annotation here.

2) Maintain marshalling and unmarshalling of request response layer seperately from the controller.

3) Maintain modularity so that it should be like a plugin play architecture.

4) I suggest you to use JAX-RS annotations so that rest service implementations both server and client can be a simple one min job and we can use existing frameworks to make it very simple.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of JPA annotation that can be used in RESTful API client?

Comment: Its in dao layer i mentioned.for pure rest client there are lot of options depending on your ease of use ranging from apache http client api to jax rs 2.0 complaint apis.

Comment: Do you mean annotations like org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource or something like javax.persistence.PersistenceContext?

Comment: i meant java persistance annotations